# Kernel Mode version of FindResource

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

I am trying to embed a binary resource into my kernel mode static library but I dont see a kernel equivalent of FindResource and LoadResource API. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: I imagine that the usual approach is to embed the content as constant data, e.g., you could easily enough write a tool to convert a binary file (or resource) into a constant array declaration written in C.  But there must be existing (and more efficient) tools to do this, hopefully someone can make some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `LdrFindResource` and `LdrAccessResource` helps you.
But this functions are undocumented and unsupported by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Harry, that's what I have done now I have written a simple tool to convert binary image to a header file

Answer (score 2):

Write a simple script to be run as a prebuild event:

1. Run `Bin2Hex` utility on your resource
2. Inject the output as an array into your source code: `char *data[] = {/* hex data */};`